# Получить от сервера html код в переменной json

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Перелопатил пол интернета, так и не нашел что искал.
При изменении количества продуктов в корзине я отправляю на сервер запрос с идентификатором и количеством единиц. Мне от сервера нужно получить три разних html блока. Я могу получить ети блоки отправив еще обратно 3 запроса на разные урл. но так будет глупо.

Делаю так. и получаю в переменных с html колом просто пустой обьект (list:{})

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '/cart/update',
            type: 'get',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (html) {
                select.closest('.product-list').replaceWith(html.list);
            }
        });
```

php

```
      $responce['list'] =// html - код;
      $responce['list'] =// html - код;
      $responce['count'] = 4;

      echo json_encode($responce, true);
```

Comment: покажите код который работает, но вы считаете его глупым.

Comment: Я обновляю количество товара. отправляю запрос на сервер. там записываю изменения в сессию корзины и отправляю доаустим назад блок корзины.
Дальше мне нужно еще обновить 2 блока. с данными по корзине. И я могу  отправить еще по запросу на каждый блок. Я щитаю это не правильно. И нужно все получить одним запросом

Comment: data -- на сервер это то что вы записываете и возвращаете

Comment: Причем  сдесь дата!?

Comment: возвращайте json такого вида: `{
  "html_1": "<p>html for block 1</p>",
  "html_2": "<p>html for block 2</p>",
  "html_3": "<p>html for block 3</p>"
}`

Comment: Глупо возвращать html в json. Вы должны получить json, а потом отработать его в вашем html как нужно

Comment: "Bykuznec  - Глупо возвращать html в json" - У меня генерируеться html елемент сайта из отдельного файла. Который я подключаю через balde. И я думаю глупее будет этот елемент генерировать еще и на стороне клиента, как вы говорите. И при изменении структуры искать его в двух файлах.

Answer (score 0):

К ссожалению пока ответа не нашел. И зделал пока вот так..

```
    $this->data['details'][] = $this->cart->get_item($data['rowid']);
        $html = "<div>";
        $html .= $this->display('product._list_creator', true);
        $html .= '<div class="basket-bk">' . $this->getCart(true) . '<div>';
        $html .= "<div>";

    echo $html;
```

И при получении..

```
    $.ajax({
    url: '/cart/update',
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (html) {
        var html = $(html);
        select.closest('.product-list').replaceWith(html.find('.product-list'));
    }
});
```